# Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry

Eliminate B from each pair of equations:

x=sinB -3cosB    and    y=sinB+2cosB

- I've tried solving this simultaneously just as the textbook has guided me through, but it still doesn't work. My initial working out was moving sinB to the left hand side and everything else to the right and solve simultaneously. But that didn't work out, I must have done something wrong, can someone please help me solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Solve for $\sin B,\cos B$

Then use $\sin^2B+\cos^2B=1$

Comment: Can you please elaborate as too how to solve for sin B?

Comment: @RedQueen10101, just subtract the equations,  you will get $\cos B$ in terms of $x,y;$ then we can use $\cos B$ to find $\sin B$. So you know how to solve simultaneous equations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system) ?

Comment: Im sorry this is sort of off topic. But do you know some program or website which makes it easier to type up complicated maths questions?

Comment: @RedQueen10101, http://www.mathcaptain.com/algebra/simultaneous-equations.html

Comment: Could you show me how to further complete the question? Im very new to the topic. So sorry if im abit slow.

Comment: @RedQueen10101,$$\sin B+2\cos B-(\sin B-3\cos B)=y-x\implies 5\cos B=y-x\implies \cos B=\frac{y-x}5$$ and from the first equation $$\sin B=x+3\cos B=x+3\cdot \frac{y-x}5=\frac{2x+3y}5$$ Now, use the last identity in the answer

Comment: what is the last identity?

Comment: $\sin^2B+\cos^2B=1$

Comment: hmm, I ended up with  4y-3x=5

Comment: the answer is x^2 +2xy +2y^2 =5    ?

Comment: @RedQueen10101, yes.

Comment: I didn't get the answer, instead I got 4y-3x=5

Comment: so how do you finish it?

Comment: @RedQueen10101, $$\left(\frac{y-x}5\right)^2+\left(\frac{2x+3y}5\right)^2=1\implies (y-x)^2+(2x+3y)^2=25\implies 5(x^2+2y^2+2xy)=25\implies x^2+2y^2+2xy=5$$